# Change the default icon for shortcuts in a specifc folder

Tags: windows-10, icons

I'm organizing a bunch of documents. These documents can be categorized into one or more categories, and each "category" will be a "folder" in Windows 10. So what I'm doing is to put all the docs in one single folder, and simply add shortcuts in the respective category folders. The thing is: I don't want to see the shortcut icon on all of these docs.

I understand that changing the icon does not do much to the fact that they are, in fact, shortcuts -- but I just want to be tricked into believing that they're the actual files.

How do I change the default shortcut icon to remove the "arrow" in a shortcut file like how it's here: https://laptoping.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/How-to-Create-Shortcut-Icons-on-Desktop-Windows-10-Tutorial.jpg

I only want this to happen in one particular folder. i.e., I want the shortcuts in other places (such as my desktop) to retain their arrows.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The overlay is system wide I believe. It can be changed but it cannot be changed for an individual folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two steps are needed.

- [Remove the arrow on *all* shortcuts](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-get-rid-shortcut-arrows-windows-10):

  - In Regedit, open `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer`
  - Create a new key, `Shell Icons`.
  - Under that key, create a new string value, `29`.
  - Set the value for that new value to `%windir%\System32\shell32.dll,-50`.
  - Reboot to see the shortcut icons without overlay.

This Registry hack to remove the arrow works only temporarily in Windows 10 ver. 1803. An alternative is to substitute a plain background icon, which can be [downloaded from Winaero.com](https://winaero.com/blog/remove-shortcut-arrow-overlay-in-windows-10/), and set its location in the the REG_SZ `29` as above... or use the [Winaero Tweaker](https://www.techspot.com/downloads/6911-winaero-tweaker.html).

- Change the icon for each folder and icon.
  [image: Change icon]

  - Right click on the folder or icon.
  - Select *Properties*.
  - For a shortcut, on the *Shortcut* tab, or for a folder, on the *Customize* tab, select *Change icon...*.
  - Select the icon if shown, or browse to a file such as `%SystemRoot%\System32\SHELL32.dll` to select another icon.
    Note that a shortcut to a customized shortcut or folder inherits the new icon, but the new shortcut can in turn be customized to yet another icon.